# Digital clock on a form should show time changing Datetime.now shows only still time

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a windows form where i used below code from DateTime Class but i want to use the timing should variable on form

```
        LblLocalTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        LblUTCTime.Text   = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

What should i do?

Comment: You have to call your set method again and again and again ...
You could do it in the draw method of the form and call this.invalidate() at the end.

Answer (score 8):

Use a Timer class,set the interval you desire

```
private void Form1_Load()
{
      Timer tmr = new Timer();
      tmr.Interval = 1000;//ticks every 1 second
      tmr.Tick+=new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
      tmr.Start();    
}

//change the label text inside the tick event
private void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      LblLocalTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      LblUTCTime.Text   = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing just sets the text one time.  You have to constantly update your label to reflect the current DateTime.  Set up a timer on one second intervals and update the labels on each Tick event.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
Timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
Timer.Interval = 1000;

private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LblLocalTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
     LblUTCTime.Text   = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
}
```

Comment: See edit for your answer